# How to initialize members of the class in kotlin when we are using both primary and secondary constructor?

Tags: class, kotlin, oop, constructor

I am new to kotlin and was learning about classes recently. I don't understand why i am getting this error "property must be initialized or abstract" for _age variable. Although I have initialized it in the secondary constructor.

```
 class Person(firstname:String,lastname:String)
{

   var _firstname: String

   var _lastname: String    
   var _age:Int            

   init{        
       _firstname=firstname 
       _lastname=lastname                        
       println("The name of the person is $firstname ")
   } 
 constructor(firstname:String="Jack",lastname:String="Sparrow",age:Int)
 :this(firstname,lastname) {    
           _age=age
           println("The age of $_firstname $_lastname is $age")
   }
```

}

Comment: What should `_age` be set to if someone calls your primary constructor?

Comment: The secondary constructor delegates to the primary constructor, but not the other way around. This means, as @gidds pointed out, that if someone calls the primary constructor directly, `_age` will never get a chance to be initialized, hence your error here. It's usually easier to make the primary constructor deal with all the state that you need, and provide secondary constructors if you want optional ways to construct instances without all the information.

Comment: As a side note, the `_` prefix is usually discouraged, especially for public properties like here.

Comment: You also might want to reconsider your use of `var` unless it's actually necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This error is telling you that there is at least one way to construct instances of your class without initializing the `_age` property.

The secondary constructor always delegates to the primary constructor, but not the other way around. This means, as @gidds pointed out, that if someone calls the primary constructor directly, the property `_age` will never get a chance to be initialized, hence your error here:

```kotlin
val person = Person("John", "Doe") // what would _age be here?
```

It's usually easier to make the primary constructor deal with all the state that you need, and provide either arguments with default values or secondary constructors if you want optional ways to construct instances without all the information.

In your case, you don't really need a secondary constructor at all here, you should just need default values for your primary constructor arguments.

Also, you can use a shorter syntax for your primary constructor, which allows you to declare its arguments and define properties of your class at the same time:

```kotlin
class Person(
    val firstname: String,
    val lastname: String,
    val age: Int = 25, // whichever default you want here
) {
    init {
        println("The name of the person is $firstname")
        println("The age of $firstname $lastname is $age")
    }
}
```

The above is quite compact, and defines the following:

- a primary constructor with arguments `firstname`, `lastname` and `age`, where `age` is an optional argument with a default value
- 3 read-only properties (because of `val`) on your class, which have the same names as the primary constructor arguments

When the constructor is called, the properties are automatically initialized with the values of the constructor argument, and then the `init` block is executed.

Side notes:

- avoid `var` as much as possible, prefer read-only `val`s instead. They are easier to reason about, for humans and for the compiler, which can do better smart casts and optimizations
- avoid the `_` prefix in general, and especially in public property (this is not very standard Kotlin style)

Comment: In the compact version of the code that you have provided, I am not able to able to understand, when the variables firstname and lastname are initialized in the init block?

Comment: @SarthakKumar they are initialized as a first step, before calling the `init` block. As you can see, the primary constructor doesn't really have a body. It just initializes properties, but its code is not written explicitly (it is generated by Kotlin). You can then add `init` blocks if you want more complex logic. They are called when your class is instantiated, but they are not really part of the primary constructor per se. You can find more info here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation and helping out with my problem.